# why this condition implies uniqueness

Tags: category-theory, morphism

Suppose that in a category
if a morphism $g$ has the same domain as $p$ and $$pu=pv$$ implies $$gu=gv$$ then $$g=tp$$ for some $t$.

Then $t$ is **unique**. Is it true; how can I (dis)prove this ?

See below:

[image]

**EDIT** for anyone who wants look up the old french papers.

[image]

Comment: The quantifiers here are somewhat unclear. Are we given morphisms $p$ and $g$ such that for *all* morphisms $u$ and $v$ (with the appropriate domain and codomain) such that $pu = pv$, we have $gu = gv$? And then the question is whether there exists a unique morphism $t$ such that $g = tp$? Or is the question whether such a morphism is unique *if* it exists?

Comment: @DanielHast For the first part of your question, yes. And for the second is precisely is **unique** *if* it exists. I think it is clearly stated in the question itself, though.See my edit.

Comment: @DanielHast I derived that $t$ must be unique just because it is in parentheses.

Comment: It looks like this condition is a **definition** for the notion of a subregular arrow. The author is not saying that every pair $(p,g)$ with this property admits a _unique_ $t$. Instead, they are saying that a pair which _does_ admit a unique such $t$ is called subregular. At least, that's how I read this.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Right, but why is an essential part of the definition in parenthesis which suggests that it can be safely omitted and in particular implied by the rest ?

Comment: Did you try constructing a counterexample?

Comment: It's a stylistic choice. To me, this reads as though unique is part of the definition (or an easy consequence of the rest of the definition) but it's not something that the author is necessarily going to need in the rest of the paper.

Comment: @posilon Yes but I couldn't find anything which would work.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor This is what I'm asking: is it an easy consequence **or** part of the definition ?

Comment: Just try constructing a minimal working counterexample. E.g. a category with four objects and as few morphisms as possible.

Comment: @posilon So you think that there is a counterexample ? I've tried but it was a mess. Hoping someone gives me a hint.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at those two references to see if they require uniqueness of $t$ or not. Maybe the parentheses denote that some authors require uniqueness while others do not.

Comment: @posilon Good idea, but the papers are old and moreover in French.

Comment: What's the source of the first screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no restrictions on your category then it's easy to see that $t$ is not necessarily unique by constructing a small counterexample.

Consider for example a category of four objects and the following morphisms, plus the four identity morphisms which I haven't drawn:

[image]

Notice that there is no ambiguity as to what is the composition of any two composable morphisms.

Notice also that you could have many morphisms $A \to B$ instead of just one; it would still be a counterexample.

Comment: In the extract posted in the question, it says that $t$ must exist "**whenever** $g$ has the same domain as $p$ and $pu=pv$ implies $gu=gv$", so it has to hold for all given choice of $g$. In your example, $p$ should be a split monomorphism if there is only one morphism $A\to B$.